# bird process is writing and reading enormous amounts of data daily

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, high-sierra, ssd

I have a MBP Retina 13" Early 2015 with macOS High Sierra and I am having an issue for a while now that is going to destroy my SSD.

The bird process is writing more than 100GB per day and reading around 40GB per day. I have iCloud Drive enabled and I have tried disabling it and re-enabling it to try and resolve this issue with no result. This has been going on for a while now so we are talking about terabytes of data.

While the SSD reads and writes are very significant, the network usage seems normal so it doesn't seem that my computer is reading and writing of the internet all the time and no I don't have a torrent client running.

I used to have development files on my iCloud Drive but soon realised that this wasn't a great idea and removed all development files but still the same issue.

I used `fs_usage` as suggested by [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/what-process-is-accessing-the-hard-drive) and saw that bird is constantly calling `pread`.

Unlike [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/what-process-is-accessing-the-hard-drive) I don't have bird just taking a part of my free space but writing again and again crazy amounts of data (far greater than the size of my SSD).

Any ideas??? :'(

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have seen that answer but this is different. It is not a matter of bird storing a lot of data but writing terabytes of I don't know what.