# Mac does not sleep automatically in Lion!

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, bug

My Macbook Pro will not sleep even though it is set in **System Preferences → Energy Saver**.

- I do not have any sharing options enabled (System Preferences → Sharing).
- I do not have "Wake for network access" enabled (System Preferences → Energy Saver).
- It does not matter if the Mac is connected to a power source.
- I've reset the SMC and the PRAM, but this did not help.

I'm running OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was looking at the same problem just the other day and found [this related post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/why-wont-my-macbook-pro-automatically-sleep). It's aimed at 10.6, but contains a reasonable amount of research and helpful info

Comment: @binarybob Thanks for the link! I really did not see that. Apparently the answers haven't been very sufficient when you look at the votes. I'll try a Safe Boot to see if I'm still affected then. How did you solve this problem for yourself?

Comment: @binarybob This problem *does occur* in Safe Mode as-well!

Comment: How about bluetooth and/or a magic mouse?

Comment: @Richard I don't have any external devices connected. Bluetooth and infrared are disabled.

Comment: @gentmatt I've unfortunately not found a solution either. I've sort of dodged the issue up until now by either closing the lid on my MBP, or doing a forced sleep which does work. Its just the idle sleep that doesn't :-( I did find that often it would go to sleep several minutes after the set period, say 9 mins if it was set to 5 mins, but that was far from reproducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another safe boot revealed that the auto sleep mode actually is working. I believe that it would probably have worked the last time I've tried it as well  - but, since the sleep occurs *several minutes later* than the time defined in the Energy Saver settings, I did not notice this.

What about the 'normal' boot?

I've basically tested the auto sleep with all my menu extras enabled one by one, because the `iotop` command mentioned by @StuWilson didn't show anything helpful to me. As it turns out the menu extra [Stack Exchange Notifier](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) caused insomnia.

Comment: Makes sense–it must be regularly polling the site looking for updates.

Comment: @jaberg But what about apps like Tweetdeck? It also continuously connects to various servers.

Comment: sorry re: 'iotop' did that show anything helpful? from the answer it reads as it didn't.

Comment: I suspect, but don't know, that there is a *proper* way to code tasks like this that instructs the applications to lie dormant when the system is sleeping. As I think deeper, I haven't noticed (but haven't looked for) any problems with my MBA staying asleep the w/SEN menu item running and I *think* the system has been going to sleep on schedule, but wii have to test this later.

Comment: @StuWilson It did not post anything about the SEN.

Comment: @StuWilson Nevermind, I just noticed that you edited my answer. :) That edit is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @gentmatt no problem, it just confused me, hence the question and the edit.  Glad we got to the bottom of this one.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest cause of macs not entering idle state is usually disk activity.

I'd suggest that you boot into Safe Boot mode then use Activity Monitor to see if any processes are causing IO operations.

If you do see activity then try using iotop in terminal, it will give you a breakdown of Process ID (PID) and the app or process name doing the IO operations.

```
sudo iotop -C 5 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later this day and let you know.

Comment: This time, when booting into safe mode, sleep would work fine. I believe that this should have worked the last time as well. However, I did not notice this because the sleep only occurs *several minutes later* than the time defined in the Energy Saver settings. I've managed to isolate the cause of the problem to the Stack Exchange Notifier App.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be your problem, but I've had the same issue for a long time and couldn't find an answer for me, so I'll post what worked for me in case someone comes along later.

My MacBook Pro (and later, my iMac, since I used Migration Assistant) would not sleep when left idle for anything. It would sleep with the lid closed, or if I explicitly told it to, but would not sleep when left alone, as it should have per my preferences in Energy Saver.

I had already checked `pmset -g assertions` and turned off sharing and other wake-on-LAN settings, and nothing seemed to work. Monitoring `pmset -g pslog`, I found that the computer would go to sleep at the scheduled time, and wake back up a few seconds later, reporting as `wake reason` only whatever had been called last—even if it was the power button (that is, it said I had pressed the power button when I had not. That scared me). I had read this and a dozen other answers and forums and couldn't get anywhere.

I found a hint by checking `pmset -g log` which was a little more detailed than `pslog`. It turned out that every time the computer went to sleep, a process "cancelled" like so:

```
3/13/13 12:00:12 AM CDT  Sleep                  Software Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                              6492 secs 
3/13/13 12:00:12 AM CDT  Cancelled              Kernel: Response from WDDMService is to cancel state change
```

Looking up WDDMService in Activity monitor, it turned out to be a background daemon that was installed by the notorious "SmartWare" that came on a Western Digital External drive. So I killed the process, and the computer went to sleep as it should! Since I don't use the software, I removed it from launchd (which I think it called the .plist? I didn't really know what I was doing there) so it wouldn't appear again. Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Mavericks with a brand new Macbook  Pro Retina (Late 2013).  When I closed the lid and left the laptop closed overnight it **never** went to sleep.  In the morning, the battery would be **dead** or ***very* low**.

As it turns out... my problem was due to a piece of software installed by my company's IT:

### Symantec Encryption Desktop (SED)

As noted in [this SED setup article](https://it.ucsf.edu/services/pgp/mac-symantec-encryption-desktop-pgp-install-guide#WDEMac):

> Hibernation also called Safe Sleep is not supported with PGP WDE, when a Mac goes to sleep and runs out of battery power the Mac will shut down and not go into safe sleep. It’s important to turn off the machine if it will run out of battery power

Here is [Symantec's official reason why](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH149486)

> PGP Whole Disk Encryption is not supported with hibernation mode in the Mac OS X. In Mac OS X, an image file is created upon hibernation of the system. Once power is restored, the state of the system is restored, including any open programs or other processes that were running. The location of this file is in /var/vm/sleepimage and is the size of RAM memory on the system.
>
> This mode may be referred to as Safe Sleep, Deep Sleep, or Hibernation. This is not the normal Sleep mode in which the power can remain on, but the system is essentially idle. This mode does not keep an image of the processes, but rather the information is stored in the RAM memory.
>
> The Mac OS X operating system does not support foreign file systems for hibernation. Mac OS X Hibernation mode is not supported with "boot != root". This "boot != root" is essentially the system used by Mac to boot a foreign file system. For PGP Whole Disk Encryption to boot a system, a special file system is used which is considered foreign. As PGP Whole Disk Encryption is considered a foreign file system, hibernation mode is not supported by the Mac OS X.
>
> As a safeguard to prevent system issues and data loss, PGP Desktop disables the hibernation mode on Mac OS X. Although Sleep will still work, deep sleep does not build a sleep image.